# Initialize EF POCO scalar properties in constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, constructor, initialization

Are there any negative effects in creating a default constructor in my entity classes for initialization?

```
public User() {
    Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
    StateId = STATES.NEW.ID;
}
```

I want to do that to reduce code for any initialization of POCO in client classes like:

```
var user = new User() 
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow, 
    StateId = STATES.NEW.ID 
};
```

Comment: No, there are no negative effects. I've done this and I have seen other people do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there are no negative effects, as long as you have a public, parameterless constructor so EF is able to create objects. In fact, this is how you are supposed to create default properties with Entity Framework.